# Find file sequence with RegExp in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, filenames

I have a simple question:

How do I use RegExp in Javascript to find strings that matches this filter:
`*[0-9].png` in order to filter out file sequences.

For example:

```
bird001.png
bird002.png
bird003.png
```

or

```
abc_1.png
abc_2.png
```

Should ignore strings like `abc_1b.png` and `abc_abc.png`
I'm going to use it in a getFiles function.

```
var regExp = new RegExp(???);
var files = dir.getFiles(regExp);
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

If I have a defined string, let's say

```
var beginningStr = "bird";
```

How can I check if a string matches the filter

`beginningStr[0-9].png`

? And ideally beginningString without case sensitivity. So that the filter would allow Bird01 and bird02.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything followed by `[0-9]` and ened by `.png`:

```
/^.*[0-9]\.png$/i
```

Or simply without begining (regex will find it itself):

```
/[0-9]\.png$/i
```

Comment: Hi, I updated the question, do you have a solution for that one?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you need a regex that matches files with names which:

1. Begin with letters `a-z`, `A-Z`
2. Optionally followed with single `_`
3. Followed by one or more digits
4. Ending with `.png`

Regex for this is `[a-zA-Z]_{0,1}+\d+\.png`

You could try online regex builders which offer immediate explanation of what you write.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly,

```
var re = /\s[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]+\.png/g;
var filesArr = str.match(re);
filesArr.sort();// you can use own sort function
```

Please specify what is the dir variable

Comment: Why the star becomes latin alphabet only?